# Fortify issue of newLine

Tags: java, fortify

I am stuck into an issue in java. I have below code:

```
String newLine=System.getProperty("line.seperator");
```

and when I am calling it using:

```
this.writer.write(newLine); //fortify issue
```

It is giving fortify issue at the commented area of Formula injection.

What can be the solution?

Comment: What is the Fortify error you are seeing?

Comment: Hey Jose, I have got fortify scan report and it is just showing me issue type that is Formula Injection , I am not able to see any error.

Comment: Question, is there a finite number of possible line-seperators your software supports?

Comment: There is a property [`"line.separator"`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html)  Could it be a typo?

Comment: @JoseMartinez no there is not issue like finite number of line-seperators , the issue is of potential threat that someone could change it during run time as setProperty or getProperty doesn't make persistent changes

Comment: @AlexRudenko no there is no typo

Comment: @RupendraSingh - `seperator` is not equal to `separator`

Answer (score 1):

My suggested fix would be to have a finite number of `line.separator`s.  For example `\n`, `|`, `,`, `|||`, etc..  Then you can create a static map that contains them all.  You would then use the `line.separator` passed, and fey off of that to get the value of the real `line.separator` you will use.

```
Map supportedLineSeperators = Map.of("NEWLINE", "\n", "COMMA", ",", "PIPE", "|", "TRIPLE_PIPE", "|||");

String lineSeperatorKey = System.getProperty("line.separator");

String newLine = supportedLineSeperators.get(lineSeperatorKey);
```

You'll have to add in support for a default line separator.  You really shouldn't allow any line.seperator because it can lead to malicious code injections or bug/defects if the wrong line.seperator is passed.

Comment: will it fix the fortify issue ?

Comment: yes.  this will fix it because you are not using values that were provided from outside the code.  Hence no injection security issues.

Answer (score 0):

Fortify considers the value returned by `System.getProperty("line.separator");` as unclean user input, and therefore, is concerned when you start writing this unclean string straight into an output where unclean strings aren't allowed.

Also note that `System.getProperty("line.seperator");` always returns null... you typoed the key name :)

### Suggested fix

Do you NEED to follow line.separator? That makes virtually no sense here; if this is an application that runs fully locally (no servers or HTTP involved, it makes files that are intended for consumption solely on the machine that runs this software and nowhere else), it MIGHT make sense to follow the platform's line separator preferences, though in practice, other than windows 'notepad.exe', no software that is at this point used on the planet is going to barf on `\n` as a separator. If that `writer` is not a local file but anything else, then using the local separator preference straight up makes no sense at all.

In other words, forget about the line.separator property. Not just for this project, for all projects. To separate lines, use `"\n"`. Period. In passing, fortify will no longer consider it a problem. `line.separator` is sometimes (rarely, but sometimes) appropriate for any locally run application that produces files meant solely for consumption on the local machine. And it is never appropriate anywhere else.

### Otherwise..

If somehow following platform line separator is important (and I really, really doubt that), an easy way out is to lock down what it can be: Either `"\r\n"` or `"\n"` so just use an if:

```
String newLine = "\r\n".equals(System.getProperty("line.separator")) ? "\r\n" : "\n";
```

Now fortify notices that either way it's an in-code constant and no longer considers this unclean.